# Unable to install rvm on mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: rvm, osx-snow-leopard, tar

I've been unsuccessfully trying to install RVM on my Snow Leopard, but everysingle way I tried ended in the same way:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=1.9.3
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13707  100 13707    0     0   8880      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 33350
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1062k  100 1062k    0     0   198k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--  288k
tar: unrecognized option `--strip-components'
Pour en savoir davantage, faites: `tar --help'.
Could not extract RVM sources.
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: See: http://portertech.ca/2010/03/26/homebrew--rvm--awesome/ ?

Answer (score 0):

this could happen with `tar` version from `fink`, try `ls -l /sw/bin/gtar` - in case you do not use `fink` just remove it with `rm -rf /sw`.